# drawable in a row for a listview changes row height

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview, drawable

I am trying out making a listview which has a drawable set as the background for each row. Unfortunately, my drawable is pretty big and the height of the rows grows to accommodate the background image. The question is, is there a simple way to have the image scale to just fit into the row (regardless of the height of the row itself since that needs to be dependent on the content of the row aside from the drawable in question)

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Not sure what you're background drawable looks like, but have you tried making a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) out of it?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 options here:
1. Pre-scale the drawable to be of the size which looks good to you. You will need to prepare different sizes for different screen densities (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi)
2. Convert it to a 9-path image
3. Instead of setting the drawable as a background, create an ImageView in your layout pass your image to it and set the needed scaleType option

Anyway, scaling a big image for each row in a list doesn't sound as a good idea, because it will greatly affect your UI performance